# How do I AirDrop from a MacBook to its tethered iPhone?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, tethering, airdrop

My MacBook (OSX Yosemite 10.10.5) is tethered to my iPhone (10.0.2) in order to provide Internet access.

How do I AirDrop **from** my Macbook **to** an app on my iPhone?

Currently I have to use Dropbox, ie. move the file into Dropbox, wait for the (possibly large file) to upload, then download it on my iPhone to the desired app (causing another sync).

Comment: Did you try tethering over usb so that wifi was free to airdrop? You don’t need a network either to airdrop.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that if you have personal hotspot on, the device that is supplying that hotspot will not be able to send or receive via airdrop

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn off **Personal Hotspot** before you can AirDrop.

**AirDrop** transfers data over Wi-Fi between the two peer devices (in this case, your MacBook and your iPhone). Since your iPhone is providing a **Personal Hotspot** via Wi-Fi, that connection is not available for AirDrop.

If turning Personal Hotspot off and on repeatedly is too cumbersome, you can provide tethering through USB instead. Then your Wi-Fi connection will always be available for AirDrop.

Answer (score 1):

Like Phong said, you will need to turn off your Personal Hotspot before you can AirDrop since it is using the network from your phone. However your MacBook does not need to be on a Wi-Fi network in order to send or receive files through AirDrop. As long as *both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are on on both of your devices*, it can send the files without being connected to each other or the internet.

To send things through AirDrop on your Mac, simply **right-click** on the file(s) you want to send, mouse over **share**, then click on **AirDrop**. Then once your iPhone shows up, click **send** and click **accept** on your iPhone.

If you would like to know how AirDrop works, you can go here and it explains it in easy-to-understand terms: https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-airdrop-how-does-it-work-1994512

Answer (score 1):

Just in case in anyone is coming across this for a more recent version of macos (Catalina 10.15.5) and iOS (13.5.1) If I am tethered using Bluetooth, rather than Wi-Fi, I can use Personal Hotspot and Airdrop at the same time.

Comment: The OP's question is from 3 years ago.  If you're not referring to the same macOS and iOS versions then it would be helpful if you can add your versions to the answer.  This way, the reader can determine if your answer is helpful or not.